# Rename all files in google drive by using google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to rename my all Audio files in particular folder in my  drive by using google script.
How to get original name of file? And replace with new name that will erase first 23 words and remain all name as it was. I didn't understand how to do that.

I try following script.

```
​    function non_native_file_name_changer(folderID,fileName,fileType,iterator) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('ID');
  var files = folder.getFilesByType(fileType);
  var count = 1

  while(files.hasNext()){
    var file = files.next()

    if(iterator === true){    
      file.setName(file.getName().slice(-23));
    }else{
     file.setName(fileName);
    };
  };
};


function start(){
  var folder_ID = "ID";
  var file_name = "Audio";
  var file_type = "audio/amr";
  var have_a_count = true;

  var go = non_native_file_name_changer(folder_ID,file_name,file_type,have_a_count);
};
```

This not work... 
Please help.

To call all files from folder but no run.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want the files from a specific folder but you didn't open a specific folder. What happens if you use

```
var id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(id).getFiles();
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  Logger.log(file.getName());
}
```

Comment: Unique how? Right now the script just goes to each file and prints the current name to the log.